# How is twitter-text-js AutoLink meant to be used?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I don't seem to get how the autolink function of the [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js) lib works.

Does it scan the entire page and automatically create links or do I provide it with text and it returns linkified text back? I've tried both and neither seems to work.

Anyone know how it works or got a working example?